# Excel to SQL Server 2008 R2 error on insert

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

I am trying to insert Excel data into SQL Server 2008 R2 using asp.net webforms and a stored procedure.

Here is the code for the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_ImportFromExcel07]
   @SheetName varchar(20),
   @FilePath varchar(100),
   @HDR varchar(3),
   @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)

    IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
      SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE'
    ELSE
      SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @TableName + ' FROM OPENDATASOURCE'

    SET @SQL = @SQL + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @HDR + ''''''')...['
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SheetName + ']'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

when I execute it through SQL Server Management Studio it runs without error but in my web application this error shows up

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error. Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

I am pretty sure that I installed the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider because it shows on the link server provider of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Solutions attempted:

- SQL Server is running under administrators account.

and this:

```
USE [master] 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
GO
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the JET OLEDB driver, not the Access one?  Does the Access one allow the same type of interaction with Excel that the JET one does?

Comment: haven't tried yet but from the result of executing the stored procedure from SQL Server studio it works perfectly the only difference is that i am executing the stored procedure trough my web application on a local computer it works but on my hosted server it generates the error stated above

Comment: Silly question but did you install the driver on the hosted server in the same place that it is on your local machine?

Comment: yes i installed it..the problem stated above was on the hosted server as stated above everything was installed prior to executing the stored procedure trough Sql Server Management Studio which was a success but on my web application it returns an error i have also given sufficient permission to the administrators account where the excel file is being uploaded

Comment: Did you see the registry hack located [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb2dc720-f8f9-4b93-b5d1-cfb4f8a8b1cb/the-ole-db-provider-microsoftaceoledb120-for-linked-server-null-reported-an-error-access)?  Also, you need to give the SQL Server Agent the correct permissions to the file location.

Comment: i have a question should the SQL Server Agent be running?because on my server it is turned off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46016/discussion-between-tteeple-and-angelogogo)

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything having it turned on.  Note though, SQL Server Express does not include Agent functionality.